# Sentencia BASH: variable formada por otra variable

Tags: bash

estoy intentando ejecutar este código:

```
#!/bin/bash

VIDEOS_BORDER=/home/user/LipReadingBBC/lipread_mp4/BORDER/train/

PALABRA='BORDER'

echo "$VIDEOS_${PALABRA}"*.mp4
```

Esperaba este resultado:
/home/user/LipReadingBBC/lipread_mp4/BORDER/train/BORDER.mp4

Pero lo que obtengo es:
BORDER*.mp4

¿Alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias

Comment: Tienes que modificar la última linea: `echo "${VIDEOS_BORDER}${PALABRA}".mp4`

Comment: No son necesarios lo corchetes, pero podrías realizarlo de esta forma echo "${VIDEOS_BORDER}${PALABRA}".mp4

Comment: Creo que el esta intentando imprimir cada uno de los videos .mp4 que empiezan por la palabra 'BODER' seguido de las demas coincidencias `*` seguido de '.mp4'

Comment: No sé si es esto lo que pides: [¿Cómo hago con Bash que un nombre de variable sea dinámico?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/483234/83)

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas concatenar cadenas, realizalo de esta forma:

```
var1="Hola"
var2=" Stackoverflow!"
resultado ="$var1$var2"
echo "$resultado"
```

la salida sería

```
Hola Stackoverflow!
```

Por lo tanto basado en lo que tratas de realizar en tu pregunta, sería:

```
#!/bin/bash
VIDEOS_BORDER=/home/user/LipReadingBBC/lipread_mp4/BORDER/train/
PALABRA='BORDER'
echo "$VIDEOS_BORDER$PALABRA".mp4
```

como puedes ver no son necesarios los corchetes ( `{` y `}` )la salida sería:

```
/home/user/LipReadingBBC/lipread_mp4/BORDER/train/BORDER.mp4
```