# ¿Cómo hago con Bash que un nombre de variable sea dinámico?

Tags: bash, variables

Resulta que tengo la necesidad de llamar a una variable de forma... variable. Es decir, el nombre de la variable va a variar según un parámetro, por lo que debo poder llamar dinámicamente a la variable.

Si tengo:

```
var_foo="hola esto es foo"
var_bar="hola esto es bar"
```

Después en algún punto del código debo pedir al usuario que me dé una cadena, sea "foo" o "bar" y, según eso, llamar o bien a `$var_foo`, o bien a `$var_bar`.

¿Existe alguna manera de hacerlo?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553089/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que pretendes hacer se llama 'variable indirection' en inglés, algo así como *falsear una variable*.

Para hacerlo, debes usar la sintaxis:

```
${!variable}
```

De modo que Bash expandirá el nombre de "$variable" y lo usará como nombre de la variable a la que acudir.

Un ejemplo para aclararlo, donde este código:

```
foo="esto es lo que vale foo"
variable="foo"
echo "$variable"
echo "${!variable}"
```

Devuelve

```
foo
esto es lo que vale foo
```

---

En tu caso concreto, solamente debes decir:

```
$ variable="bar"
$ var="var_$variable"
$ echo "${!var}"
hola esto es bar
```

Puedes leer más al respecto en la Guía de Bash, sección [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> **${!prefix*}**
> **${!prefix@}**
> Expands to the names of variables whose names begin with prefix, separated by the first character of the IFS special variable. When ‘@’ is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each variable name expands to a separate word.

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción es usar el comando `eval`, el cual es una **shell builtin** o **una orden interna del interprete**, lo cual es también efectivo y rápido.
El comando eval:

> Ejecuta argumentos como una orden del intérprete de ordenes.

Esto quiere decir que los argumentos que recibe son un comando o función junto con las opciones y argumentos de dicho comando o función. Por ejemplo:

```sh
$ foo="var"
$ var="esto es var"
$ eval echo "$foo" 

var
```

Eso parece poco útil, pero sigamos aprendiendo de eval:

> Combina los ARGumentos en una sola cadena, usa el resultado como
> entrada para el intérprete, y ejecuta las órdenes resultantes.

Esto dice que `eval` creara en una instrucción para bash con todos los argumentos dados a `eval`. Veamos los pasos de `eval` siguiendo con el ejemplo anterior:

```sh
# Paso 0: ejecutar eval
$ eval echo "$foo"
# Paso 1(esto no lo vemos pero ocurre 100%): crear la instrucción
'echo var'
# Paso 2: ejecutar la instrucción  
var
```

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior podemos imaginar el gran poder que tiene `eval` al momento de hacer que un nombre de variable sea dinámico, podemos hacerlo:

```
# Paso 0:
$ eval echo "/$$foo" # Aquí es necesario escapar a '$' para que en el 
                     # paso 1 se mantenga el '$' literal y la instrucción
                     # creada use la variable y NO eval.
# Paso 1:
'echo $var'
# Paso 2:
esto es var
```

Para tu caso:

```sh
$ var_foo="hola esto es foo"
$ var_bar="hola esto es bar"

$ input="foo"
$ eval echo "\$var_$input"
hola esto es foo
```

Y para tener en cuenta:
Si algún día estamos trabajando con ficheros o nombres que contengan espacios, es necesario que en `eval` escapemos las comillas para que en el **paso 1** la instrucción generada lo use como **un** argumento y no como **mas de uno**. Por ejemplo:

```
# creamos 2 directorios para la prueba
$ mkdir "directorio con espacios"
$ mkdir "directorio_con_guion_bajo"

# No tendremos problemas con el directorio con guion bajo, así que veamos
# que problemas tiene usar eval con ficheros con espacios
$ input=" con espacios" 

# Queremos ver los permisos del directorio con espacios
# paso 0:
$ eval ls -ld "directorio$input"
# paso 1:
'ls -ld directorio con espacios' # algo anda mal... tenemos 3 argumentos para
                                 # la instrucción ls -ld
# paso 2(probablemente tengamos una salida así): 
ls: no se puede acceder a 'directorio': No existe el archivo o el directorio
ls: no se puede acceder a 'con': No existe el archivo o el directorio
ls: no se puede acceder a 'espacios': No existe el archivo o el directorio
```

Entonces si queremos forzar que la instrucción creada por `eval` se mantenga con los argumentos deseados, es necesario escapar las comillas:

```sh
# paso 0:
$ eval ls -ld \""directorio$input"\" # o eval ls -ld \"directorio$input\"
# paso 1:
'ls -ld "directorio con espacios"'
# paso 2:
drwxrwxr-x 2 soul soul 4096 sep 13 07:52 'directorio con espacios'
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, gracias por ella. Nótese que [`eval` es potencialmente peligrosa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/1983854), pero bien usada puede ser muy útil.

Comment: Muy interesante lo de eval peligroso. @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' ¿Usas algun tipo de hack que no me deja mencionarte en los comentarios de otra pregunta?

Comment: El viejo y riesgoso ´eval´. Es como tener s**o sin protección.