# Como declarar variables dinamicas y usarlas en un bucle (BASH)

Tags: bash, variables, bucles

He declarado variables en un bucle for de la siguiente manera:

```
do
        declare "dis$j=$(echo $var2 | cut -d ' ' -f $j)"
done
```

Pero no consigo llamarlas en el mismo bucle para realizar una operación, para expresarme mejor adjunto

```
do
        declare "dis$j=$(echo $var2 | cut -d ' ' -f $j)"
        echo $dis1  #esta funciona, pero lo quiero llamar con la j para acceder al que toca en el bucle
        echo "$dis$j" #un intento erroneo por mi parte de llamar a la variable declarada anteriormente 
done
```

En conclusión, no se llamar a las variables que he declarado anteriormente en el bucle para realizar más operaciones.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo hago con Bash que un nombre de variable sea dinámico?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483234/c%c3%b3mo-hago-con-bash-que-un-nombre-de-variable-sea-din%c3%a1mico)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar una tercera variable para almacenar el nombre de la variable cuyo valor quieres recuperar

```
varname=dis$j
```

Una vez hecho esto, puedes recuperar su valor así

```
echo ${!varname}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! ya funciona